# extract data from unformatted CSV file

Tags: javascript, php

I want to display only certain parts from some.csv on webpage.
I used following code to display the whole row but it doesn't look good.

some.csv

```
"1","[('1012', 5), ('1046', 5), ('1052', 5), ('1056', 4.9910199299984184), ('1030', 4.8534167927670344), ('1040', 4.8212814442619543), ('1035', 4.7661155679960796), ('1034', 4.6870279945429703), ('1042', 4.5541209598953358), ('1027', 4.5151900893812948)]"

"2","[('1049', 5), ('1016', 4.6133266327772251), ('1010', 4.5357481760897569), ('1046', 4.3349671883556038), ('1050', 4.3227509505599846), ('1037', 4.2902806273386966), ('1041', 4.2507193844291828), ('1053', 4.0984615265310147), ('1009', 4.098439317076469), ('1030', 4.0)]"

"3","[('1012', 4.9811840834706604), ('1016', 4.8312378650104533), ('1041', 4.7528923569042405), ('1049', 4.5049427949269853), ('1050', 4.3853256507131384), ('1045', 4.1598878939000565), ('1005', 4.1014830595313585), ('1022', 4.0958233778390403), ('1054', 4.0854105427315339), ('1024', 4.061922071985868)]"
```

code.php

```
<?php
    $f = fopen("C://xampp/htdocs/Game/python/some.csv", "r");
    $i = 0;
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        $i++;
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($line as $cell) {
                if($i==1)
                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    fclose($f);
?>
```

what I want is the output should look like this:

```
1012
1046
1052
1056
1030
1040
1035
1034
1042
1027
```

Comment: PHP will parse the CSV like this: `array("1", "[('1012', 5), ('1046', 5), ('1052', 5), ('1056', 4.9910199299984184), ('1030', 4.8534167927670344), ('1040', 4.8212814442619543), ('1035', 4.7661155679960796), ('1034', 4.6870279945429703), ('1042', 4.5541209598953358), ('1027', 4.5151900893812948)]")`, so it' easy to dump the first element, but difficult for the other one, I would loop through the string and cut all the numbers between apostrophes('). The best solution would be if you can get a proper CSV as source

Comment: And how does the output look like now?

Comment: So, you're php is outputting table elements, but you don't want a table, you just want a comma-separated line of values?

Comment: he wants the 1st element of the pair on every line

Comment: @LudovitMydla     1[('1012', 5), ('1046', 5), ('1052', 5), ('1056', 4.9910199299984184), ('1030', 4.8534167927670344), ('1040', 4.8212814442619543), ('1035', 4.7661155679960796), ('1034', 4.6870279945429703), ('1042', 4.5541209598953358), ('1027', 4.5151900893812948)]

Comment: BTW, that's *not* a normal-looking csv file. The second value in each line looks JSON-y, but it's not standard JSON due to the single-quoted values. Are you generating the contents of the file?

Comment: yeah i get that on my setup obviously wrong

Comment: @JonathanM actually i want to display in a table but don't know how to do it directly, So if it is comma-separated table can be created

Comment: @JonathanM Yes, the some.csv file is created in python and these are the recommendations(ids) with predicted ratings

Comment: Do you need the 1st number on envery line? 1,2,3

Comment: the problem is the 2nd part of the line is not a standard format so you probably would need a regex for that.

Comment: @Geomorillo No, I don't want to display it

Comment: look at the answer provider by Don't Panic it should work ok if you adapt it a little

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, the second element in the array produced by `fgetcsv` looks like Python code. You can extract the first element from each of those tuples with a regex.

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    preg_match_all("/'(\d+)'/", $line[1], $matches);

    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($matches[1] as $number) {
        echo "<td>$number</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

If the CSV is produced by a Python script, it would be better to modify that script so that it only outputs the numeric values you need in the CSV file, or outputs the results in a format that PHP can handle directly, like [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html).

I'm not sure exactly how you want to format the result as a table, so I'm kind of guessing at that part, but you should be able to do whatever you need with it once you get those numbers in an array.

Comment: You forgot the <table> tag or else it would not display correctly, should be outside the while construct, however this should be the acepted answer

Comment: @Geomorillo I didn't forget it. I left out other parts as well, opening/closing the file, etc. I just wanted to show how to handle the lines and figured they could run with it from there. I assume the table, tbody, and whatever else is already included in code the OP didn't provide here.

Comment: The above code gives output like this: '10121046105210561030104010351034104210271049101610101046105010371041105310091030'

Comment: @ajay were you wanting each of the numbers like 1012, 1046, etc. in a separate cell, or as CSV in a single cell?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Separate cells